# Jhipster 2.27.2 : relationship doesn't seem to be well created

Tags: jhipster

I am using Jhipster 2.27.2
I have created an entity : collaborateur(nom,prenom)
I have created an entity : societeClient with relationship with collaborateur :

> Generating relationships with other entities ? Do you want to add a
>   relationship to another entity? Yes
>   ? What is the name of the other
>   entity? collaborateur
>   ? What is the name of the relationship?
>   collaborateur
>   ? What is the type of the relationship? one-to-many
>   ? What is the name of this relationship in the other entity ?
>   societeClient

When running mvn I am getting this error :

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an
>   unknown target entity property:
>   com.techvalley.rhtechvalley.domain.Collaborateur.societeClient in
>   com.techvalley.rhtechvalley.domain.SocieteClient.collaborateurs

societeClient property doesn't exist in Collaborateur class.
Is it normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior: you did not create the societeClient relationship in collaborateur before creating the other entity.

This is documented here: https://jhipster.github.io/managing-relationships/

To fix your entity, you can read 'Generating an entity a second time'
https://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-entity/